# Refined ratio test with $1/e$ bound

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove the following ratio test for the convergence of a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$. The statement is taken from [here](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txte/2/txc3ea2d.htm) (sorry, I couldn't find an English variant of it) and can be reformulated as follows:

> Let $a_n > 0$ for $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $q \in \left[0, \frac{1}{e} \right)$ be such that 
>   $$ \left( \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right)^n \le q, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. $$ 
>   Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.

My attempt for a prove of the statement goes as follows:
$$
a_n 
= 
\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} \cdot \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} \cdots \frac{a_2}{a_1} \cdot a_1
\le
q^{\frac{1}{n-1}} \cdot q^{\frac{1}{n-2}} \cdots q^{1} \cdot a_1
=
q^{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}} a_1.
$$
Now, I would like to use the comparison test but I am unable to prove that the series 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} q^{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}}
$$
converges. This might be done by using the comparison test again by proving the inequality
$$
q^{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}} \le \left( 1 - \frac{1}{e} + q \right)^{n-1},
$$
but I don't know how to pull that off either. Could anyone give me a hint as how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k} \le \ln n + 1$$
Can you follow from here?

Comment: I tried to edit your answer but it got rejected. Anyway, the inequality $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \ge \ln n + \frac{1}{n}$ helped. Thanks for hinting me in the right direction!